# Android: Callback in an activity (fragment) is triggered with same value from a Service when the time between two triggers is very short

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, android-service

I have a Service which is connected to a socket in a thread. When the socket receives a message it triggers a callback in a fragment via a (static) interface. Now, when two messages are received in a very short time (.3 sec) the callback is triggered twice but with the same return value.

**Code:**
In the service I have declared the interface like this:

```
public interface OnVideoViewTokenReceived {
    void videoViewTokenReceived(String videoStreamToken, String cameraId);
}
public static void setOnVideoViewTokenReceived(OnVideoViewTokenReceived _onVideoViewTokenReceived) {
    Log.d(TAGSHRDL, "_onVideoViewTokenReceived set");
    onVideoViewTokenReceived = _onVideoViewTokenReceived;
}
public static OnVideoViewTokenReceived onVideoViewTokenReceived;
```

and in a thread, service is connecting to a socket and receiving message frm it:

```
networkThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ...
            socket.addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) throws Exception {
                    ....
                    streamToken = messageJSON.getJSONObject("payload").getString("token");
                                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); //!!!Without this, token will not be received in the fragment
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        onVideoViewTokenReceived.videoViewTokenReceived(streamToken, camId);
                                    }
                                });
                       }
                           }
    };
    networkThread.start();
```

and callback in my fragment:

```
GeneralSocketService.setOnVideoViewTokenReceived(new GeneralSocketService.OnVideoViewTokenReceived() {
        @Override
        public void videoViewTokenReceived(String videoStreamToken, String camId) {
               for (int i = 0; i<9 ; i++){
     ....}
```

Now here in my fragment, it all works well, but when the time between two messages is very short, the callback is triggered twice but with the same return value of `videoStreamToken`. I have used `synchronized()` as well but I had no luck. What should I do?

Comment: Can you try with livedata? to listen rather than callback?

Comment: Thanks @RameshKumar. I'd really rather see what i pure java is the problem. there should be some flaw in my code.

Comment: That is also java, but some observer. Any way you can add a delay if you want or add a lock like synchronization one in method calling